# import pygame no module named 'pygame'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm using a mac and typed

```
pip install pygame
```

into my terminal.

The terminal said the download was successful, but when I use

```
import pygame
```

in IDLE, I get an error.

I've looked at questions similar to this one and have not found an answer. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

Comment: You may have multiple Python versions installed and ran idle and pip in different ones.

Answer (score 3):

Your terminal is referring to a different environment that the one that your IDLE environment refers to. For example Pycharm saves its python packages in the venv folder by default. Pip installing a package through the terminal would not allow you to import the package inside pycharm because you have not installed it in the venv environment.

To fix this, I believe you should use the command

```
 source activate
```

in order to activate the environment that IDLE is running. You should be able to install it, and import it then.